# How do you get gnome-shell to show the full name?

Tags: gnome

I've been using gnome-shell and I really like it.  I was wondering though if it's possible to somehow get gnome-shell to display the full name of an application in the activities->applications browser if the name is too long.  For an example of what I mean:

[image: Full name isn't shown]

I have two icons for Battle for Wesnoth in the Games filter.  Both of them apparently have names too long to display entirely and end in "...".  Is there a way to either tell gnome-shell to display the names or to have them appear as a tooltip or something?

Comment: This question looks like it could also be relevant in cases of long filenames, etc.

Comment: I played around with the **gnome-shell.css** (/usr/share/themes/[your-current-theme]), after I copied that to **/home/user/.themes**. There is a section called **Apps** where you can change the grid size of the grid on which the icons are aligned - if you make that bigger (change contact grid entry accordingly) you will see more. There is even more possible but that all kind of workaround. Unfortunately I do not know enough about CSS to add a pop-up or something when hovering the icons.

Comment: Add it as an answer.  You'll at least get an upvote from me and if nobody else responds you'll earn the bounty.

Comment: Ok, I will do so eventually. But maybe I can come up with a better solution - just need some more time.

Comment: Alternative - try another desktop environment, e.g. Cinnamon or Xfce show full names because they have the "windows start menu" design, you can search all over the internet - one of nice lists: https://linuxconfig.org/8-best-ubuntu-desktop-environments-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with the `gnome-shell.css` (/usr/share/themes/[your-current-theme]), after I copied that folder to `/home/user/.themes`. In the gnome-shell.css is a section called **Apps** where you can change the grid size of the grid on which the icons are aligned - if you make that bigger (change contact grid entry accordingly) you will see more.

I also tried to find how the pop-ups, like on the overview sidebar, work - however I could not find that. Seems like that has nothing to do with CSS.