# How to get GNOME Shell "Applications overview" to show the full name of applications

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview

This question has been asked before but that was over 6 years ago and I'm hoping to get a more updated answer.

[Old Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74824/how-do-you-get-gnome-shell-to-show-the-full-name?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Basically when I search for an application, if the name is too long it's shortened with an ellipsis (...). I want to know how to change it so that the whole name is displayed. Example: [image: When searching for "Master of Orion]

I hope it's OK to ask for an updated answer.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME Shell 64-bit.

Comment: I had the same question right after installing Master of Orion 2 too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround you may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [**Applications Overview Tooltip**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1071/applications-overview-tooltip/). It

> Shows a tooltip over applications icons on applications overview with complete application name and description.
>
> [image]
> (screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the "Arc Menu" GNOME extension and use it as a replacement for a traditional menu.

Alternatively, if you are an Emacs user with "counsel" package installed. You can use counsel-linux-app command, preferably with Emacs service enabled, you can bind a command like this to Alt-F1:

```
# try to ultilize Emacs server if it's running for near-instantaneous popup
# otherwise invoke a new Emacs process
emacsclient -nc -e "(counsel-linux-app)" -e "(delete-frame)" || emacs -q --eval "(progn (package-initialize) (counsel-linux-app) (kill-emacs))"
```

Comment: This is not causing the Application Overview to show the full program name.