# Apps Name truncated in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, search, ubuntu-dock

This question [has already been asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984562/how-to-get-gnome-shell-applications-overview-to-show-the-full-name-of-applicat).

I am hoping for the answer that I want. In the answer to that question some extension has been suggested, I do not want any extension but to show all the apps full name in multiline. I am using GNOME 3.28.2 and Ubuntu 18.04.4. How do I achieve this? It is very annoying to see apps name truncated with "..." after clicking those 9 dots of Ubuntu dock.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: AFAIK there is no other (*easy* or end-user-friendly) way than using the extension.

Comment: @pomsky Watch this, [this](https://youtu.be/RmizIHRVH_M) YouTuber has done it but did not explain how.

Comment: It uses [a patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/verdre/gnome-shell/-/tree/icon-grid-multi-line-label). As I said before, there is no other easy/end-user-friendly way.

Comment: Ok, So how do I apply this patch if I want to? It's so annoying that it is literally hindering my workflow

Comment: It seems that on GNOME 40 [this annoying bug is fixed](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/gnome-shell-show-full-application-name)