# Two shortcuts for BleachBit are created in "Show Applications" space in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, bleachbit

I installed the *BleachBit* application from *Ubuntu Software* on my Ubuntu 20.04. BleachBit installed two shortcuts in the "*Show Applications*" space. Both the shortcuts open same app.

[image: Screenshot of "Show Applications"]

So, my question is how to delete one shortcut?

Comment: Maybe, one shortcut for the root user and other for the normal users.

Comment: For the issue of truncated names of apps you [mentioned in the question initially](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1243038/1), see this: https://askubuntu.com/q/984562/480481

Comment: one of them is root and the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

The two shortcuts are intentional. One shortcut is for launching BleachBit as a normal user, but the normal user cannot clean system files under `/usr` and `/var`, so the second shortcut launches BleachBit as root to clean those other files. Assuming you want to clean everything, you need both.

If you still want to delete a shortcut, look for its `.desktop` file under `/usr/share/applications`.

By the way, you also posted this question today [on another site](https://answers.launchpad.net/bleachbit/+question/690932), and this can create extra work by having multiple people answer a single question.